# R shiny in terminal

Tags: r, shiny

```
runApp("/home/jhaseon/projects/rproj/r/scripts/shiny/")
```

is creating error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6527
Error in utils::browseURL(appUrl) : 
  'browser' must be a non-empty character string
```

I am trying to run R shiny in the terminal but I am running into the following error. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 2):

looking at the code for shiny:runApp, adding launch.browser=F should solve your issue.

```
runApp("...", launch.browser = FALSE)
```

as to why this is happening, maybe a problem with a default browser not set ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set the default browser in your system settings, e.g. for the Ubuntu it's:

*Settings -> Default Applications*

and then keep the code like:

```
runApp("path_to_your_app", launch.browser = TRUE)
```